# Hangfire Dashboard Authorization Config Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, hangfire

I've downloaded the nu-get package `Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization`

I'm trying configure the OWIN based authorization as per the docs as follows but I get intellisense error `DashboardOptions.AuthorizationFilters is obsolete please use Authorization property instead`

I also get intellisense error 
`The type or namespace AuthorizationFilter and ClaimsBasedAuthorizationFilterd not be found`

```
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Owin;
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Hangfire
    {
       public static void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
           .UseSqlServerStorage(
               "ApplicationDbContext",
                new SqlServerStorageOptions 
                  { QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) });

           var options = new DashboardOptions
           {
               AuthorizationFilters = new[]
               {
                  new AuthorizationFilter { Users = "admin, superuser", Roles = "advanced" },
                  new ClaimsBasedAuthorizationFilter("name", "value")
               }
           };

           app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);
           app.UseHangfireServer();
        }
    }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

Since the above nuget package doesnt work I've attempted to create my own custom filter:

```
public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line,
        // `OwinContext` class is the part of the `Microsoft.Owin` package.
        var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

        // Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard (potentially dangerous).
        return context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

How do I restrict to only Admin roles i.e what is the syntax?

Comment: Which version of HF you are using? Also please show the namespaces you have imported in the class.

Comment: @Yogi Hangfire core  is 1.6.1 and the Hangfire.Dashborad.Authorization is 2.1.0. I've updated the post to show namespaces.

Answer (score 26):

You need to make sure the Configure(app) method is called in your Startup.cs class before configuring your hangfire dashboard.

```
  public partial class Startup
{
    private static readonly ILog log = 
        LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod
    ().DeclaringType);


    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        //Hangfire Config
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage
            ("HangFireJobs");
        app.UseHangfireServer();

        log.Debug("Application Started");

        ConfigureAuth(app);


        //this call placement is important
        var options = new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new CustomAuthorizationFilter() }
        };
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);
    }
}
```

Then in your auth config class you can do something as simple as this :

```
  public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{ 

    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            return true; 
        }

        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: 1000% thank you for this simple answer! It's the simple things.

Comment: Thanks. This approach easy to use. Please make sure to use the above answer before the endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard(); endpoint configuration

Comment: @frank that was it for me, "order matters"!

Comment: Or just `return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");`

Answer (score 4):

Defining the dashboard options in this way worked for me -

```
    var options = new DashboardOptions
    {
        AuthorizationFilters = new List<IAuthorizationFilter>
       {
          new Hangfire.Dashboard.AuthorizationFilter { Users = "admin, superuser", Roles = "advanced" },
          new Hangfire.Dashboard.ClaimsBasedAuthorizationFilter("name", "value")
       }
    };
```

I have imported the following namespaces -

```
using System;
using Owin;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
```

Yes it is showing me the `deprecated` warning for `AuthorizationFilters` and suggest to use `Authorization`, basically the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface is going to removed in version 2.0, and `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter` interface has to be used.

For this you can create your own custom filter implementing `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter` and use this instead.

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        //Implement

        //Netcore example
        return dashboardContext.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get error `The type or namespace AuthorizationFilter does not exist in the namespace Hangfire.Dashboard`. I've used the same namespaces as yourself? Looks like this package is out of date.

Comment: I've implemented my own filter but how do I restrict to only admin roles - see my edit above?