# Where to find "IDashboardAuthorizationFilter" interface (Hangfire)

Tags: c#, dashboard, hangfire

I'm trying to implement Hangfire Authorization and I found few solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39803718/7541104) which may work for me but the i'm unable to implement the interface
IDashboardAuthorizationFilter. Not sure what namespace I have to use to get this working or If I have any missing library. Please suggest.

My package versions:
Hangfire: v 1.6.8
Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization: v 2.1.0 (latest)

I've also tried updating Hangfire to latest but haven't got any luck.

P.S: I don't have enough rep to leave comment on that post. Hence, posting as new question.

Thanks!

Update:

My Code

```
using System;
using Owin;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using System.Web;

namespace Example
{
    public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : **IDashboardAuthorizationFilter** //getting error here
    {
        public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
        {          
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:
Looks like my nuget package is up to date for Hangfire but my refernced Hangfire.Core dll is not up to date. It's 1.58 right now. It still stays the same when I re-installed the nuget package.

Comment: FYI you have access to the Hangfire source code here https://github.com/HangfireIO

Comment: Yup. I've downloaded it and tried building the solution to get the required dlls but I was looking into the problem that why the updates on packages doesn't replace the dlls automatically. Thanks.

Comment: I meant that you can find the answer to which namespace the interface belongs to from the code repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Hangfire.Core nuget package and reinstalling it worked for me. Also, I had some of the old hangfire dlls in shared library of same project and that's what causing the override of dll when I installed the new version.